# What are the options for storing Python long integers in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I need to represent instances of Python "Long integer" in MySQL. I wonder what the most appropriate SQL data type I should use.

The Python documentation (v2.7) says (for numbers.Integral):

> Long integers
>
> > These represent numbers in an unlimited range, subject to available (virtual) memory only. For the purpose of shift and mask operations, a binary representation is assumed, and negative numbers are represented in a variant of 2’s complement which gives the illusion of an infinite string of sign bits extending to the left.

My read of the MySQL documentation suggests that BIGINT is limited to 64 bits. The DECIMAL type seems to be limited to 65 digits. I can, of course, use BLOB.

The application needs to support very large amounts of data, but I don't know yet how big these long integers might get, nor how many of them I'm likely to see.

I'd like to preserve the spirit of the Python long integer definition, which suggests BLOB. I'd also like to avoid re-inventing the wheel, and so I am appealing to the stackoverflow hive-mind.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Yes if you really need unlimited precision then you'll have to use a blob because even strigns are limited.

But really I can almost guarantee that you'll be fine with a NUMERIC/DECIMAL data type. 65 digits means that you can represent numbers in the range (-10^65, 10^65). How large is this? To give you some idea: The number of atoms in the whole universe is estimated to be about 10^80. If you only need positive numbers you can further increase the range by a factor of 2 by subtracting 10^65 -1 beforehand.

Comment: Every data-type is limited by some bounds (virtual memory is also a bound); the question is then what the *actual* data is allowed to be and which data-type best supports this case.

Comment: @user2246674 Does MySQL define any limits on the size of blobs apart from limitations that appear due to memory/hard drive constraints? Obviously everything is limited due to the fact that we don't have infinite resources, but there's a big difference between having a fixed maximum size like VARCHAR(1000) and a BLOB for which you don't have to specify an upper bound explicitly

Comment: It sounds like I'm going to end up with a BLOB. I like the suggestion to use pickle (or something similar) to convert to a string (I wonder about base64).

Comment: I decided to use blobs. I already had tables to handle persistent strings, so I was able to use those. First, I split the native long into a bytearray. I then base64 encode the result, and store that. I reverse the process for loading. I've confirmed that it works for my example below ((2**64)**1024 - 1), and consumes 10K bytes rather than the 19K+ bytes of pickle/str.

Comment: @Tom If you really stores such large numbers, then I'd really use blobs and not base64 encoded strings, those have an overhead of 33%. If you're using an ORM (and if not you *really* should), that should be a trivial to implement and otherwise it shouldn't be too hard either. ((2**64)**1024 - 1) should then cost you only 7.5k bytes to store.

Comment: @Voo: Good point, I guess I forgot about the initial "b" in "blob" :)

Answer (score 2):

You could pickle and store as a String. Maybe limit the String to a VARCHAR(1000)? Can it really be longer than that? You must know something about your application.

```
>>> pickle.dumps(x)
'L122222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222223L\n.'
>>> x
122222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222223L
>>>
```

Comment: Ah, that's interesting idea. Any idea of how the length of pickle.dump(aLong) compares to str(aLong)?

Comment: @DavidJashi I don't like BLOBs and would rather have something more common and portable as VARCHAR.

Comment: After edit and Tom's clarification of his needs your solution makes much more sense.

Comment: Try "aLargeInteger=(2**64)**1024 - 1". When I pickle that, I get 19,729 characters. Yet aLargeInteger.bit_length()/8 = 8,192. Add 30% or so for base64 inefficiency, and it's still about 10K bytes. That's significantly smaller than pickle/str. I think BLOB is the answer for the column type, and I think I base64 encode the long before storing (and, of course, decode it on loading).

Answer (score 1):

Well, as Python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) states, "Long integers have unlimited precision.", which is tragic, from a point of view of any database. You will have to estimate maximum value of every field, where you intend to store those and choose minimum size integer datatype to ensure that your database stays compact and efficient. BLOB is not the type you would want to build an index on.

Comment: Which is tragic from a point of view of some data-types :D Postgres supports "very large precision numbers". (Of course, it's all limited at some point, but [up to ~150k digits](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html) *ought* to be enough for most use-cases ..)

Comment: Correct me, if I'm wrong, but aren't tinyint, int and bigint (which I suggested to choose from) fixed precision data-types?

Comment: Sure, but those are not the only database types permissible. This answer asserts that this is a universal limitation of databases (it might be a MySQL limitation, but it is not a universal limitation).

Comment: I'll quote initial question: "I need to represent instances of Python "Long integer" in MySQL." Of course, I could propose to use Oracle's number type, which can hold up to 38 decimal digits, but would it be of any use for him?

Comment: "..which is tragic, from a point of view of *any* database." A universal qualifier can easily make a true statement false - or arguably "less true". Also, MySQL can support up to 60 some digits. But there is still a practical (for some purposes) range of precision between tens and tens of thousands.

Comment: I really do need to represent numbers longer than 65 digits, if for no other reason than to truthfully say that I support persisting python datatypes. At least for the moment, I'm less concerned about searching for them in the db.

Comment: @Tom Stambaugh well, then store them as you like (BLOB, VARCHAR, TEXT). They are basically text to you, until you either search or do some math with them.

Comment: @David Jashi, I agree. Any math I'll do on them will be in Python. Everything gets turned upside down again if I need to index or search for them, but that will be tomorrow's problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The application needs to support very large amounts of data, but I
>   don't know yet how big these long integers might get, nor how many of
>   them I'm likely to see.

So you have to meet this situation squarely:

(Us): *it can't possibly get any bigger than THIS.*
 (Data):  *THIS+1*
 (Computer):  *how shall I proceed, captain?*

This fills me with questions.

Have you considered hammering out some methods before picking (a) type?  Inventing arithmetics (to match a container) sounds harder than making up a container to match the math.

First thoughts: Say you want to bring some calculation to a definite result in a given time. As the input size increases without bound, I think two things become increasingly important:

a) the exact nature of the operation.

b) defining a procedure for converging on the result.

Say I feed you an arbitrarily large number N, and you want to do operation a1.  Then you might look for a way to represent N so that you can state a corresponding number M, the number of steps of fixed length it will take you to complete a1, given input N.

Questions about these numbers:

- what information to you want to retrieve from them?
- Will they be operated on/ transformed? (... and what numerical properties preserved under transformation?)
- Will they be promiscuous  (involved in calculations with other types)?
- Is there any meaning to approximate or partial results?
- How do you want them to behave?  (are there things you DO NOT want to happen?)
- Are the represented data truly integer:  discrete, enumerable quantities measured to absolute precision?

Would it help you to examine preexisting implementations, or find someone who does this kind of math?  [mpmath](https://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) is (was recently) in active development.  The author [blogs regularly](http://fredrikj.net/blog/) about related tops.  And, in general SAGE math collects a wide range of (asymptotically fast) libraries; several of them handle arbitrarily large numbers.

---

I apologize if those considerations are naive or obvious.

Comment: I appreciate your insight. My application is more pragmatic than you suggest, I think. I need to reliably store and load instances of Python "long" (I cited the Python documentation above). No more and no less. I only need to represent them in the DB (at least for now), so for now a BLOB representation works fine. The answers to the rest of your questions are all up to Python. Once I've loaded the persistent long from the DB and answered it as a Python long (such as 123456L), my job is done.

Comment: Yay.  It was the practical problem that worried me. I pictured Python User/data <--> your database <--> user X (not necessarily Python).  So it was actually the "long" citation that got me to thinking.  ok-sure-but-how-are-you-going-to....   hahaha you don't have to.  Brilliant. Thanks for responding.